# sqoop job warehouse dir already exists

Tags: sqoop

```
Sqoop command arguments :
             job
             --meta-connect
             jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://IP:16000/sqoop
             --exec
             price_range
             --
             --warehouse-dir
             folder/transit/2018-04-16--11-48
```

log:

```
Fetching child yarn jobs
tag id : oozie-e678030f4db3e129377fc1efdcc34e9a
2018-04-16 11:49:36,693 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy  - Connecting to ResourceManager at ip-172-31-4-192.ap-south-1.compute.internal/172.31.4.192:8032
Child yarn jobs are found - application_1519975798846_265571

Found [1] Map-Reduce jobs from this launcher

Killing existing jobs and starting over:
2018-04-16 11:49:37,314 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy  - Connecting to ResourceManager at ip-172-31-4-192.ap-south-1.compute.internal/172.31.4.192:8032
Killing job [application_1519975798846_265571] ... 2018-04-16 11:49:37,334 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl  - Killed application application_1519975798846_265571 
Done​
```

This is what my typical sqoop job looks like:

```
sqoop job -Dmapred.reduce.tasks=3--meta-connect jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://IP:16000/sqoop --create job_name -- import --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --connect 'jdbc:mysql://ip2/erp?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&serverTimezone=IST' --username username --password 'PASS' --table orders --merge-key order_num --split-by order_num  --hive-import --hive-overwrite  --hive-database Erp --hive-drop-import-delims --null-string '\\N' --null-non-string '\\N' --fields-terminated-by '\001' --input-null-string '\\N' --input-null-non-string '\\N' --input-null-non-string '\\N' --input-fields-terminated-by '\001' --m 12
```

This is how I execute my jobs in oozie

```
job --meta-connect jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://ip:16000/sqoop --exec JOB_NAME-- --warehouse-dir folder/transit/${DATE}
```

Now, I recently started getting an error: output directory already exists no matter what timestamp I pass in $DATE variable. This is probably because of a server process restarting. Yesterday I could see node manager restart over and over but that's not the case today either. It randomly gives this out on any sqoop job in oozie.

I add --warehouse-dir folder/Snapshots/${DATE} while executing job so that I DON'T GET output directory already exists ever but I started getting this yesterday out of nowhere.

Currently, I do not see any flags about services acting up however namenode pause duration is concerning at regular intervals. How do I fix this?

This err message makes it pretty intuitive that it is happening since warehouse dir gets created before it attempts to restart the job however the whole purpose of using warehouse-dir was to create a transitional directory so that I won't get this error. How do I fix this?

```
Found [1] Map-Reduce jobs from this launcher
Killing existing jobs and starting over:
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use `—create-hive-table` when you're trying to import data into hive and you're using `hive-overwrite` so it will be applicable when you have table in your hive instead of directory so try to create table from sqoop so when you retrigger the job it will overwrite the table data.

```
--warehouse-dir /user/cloudera/ingest/raw/helloworld
--fields-terminated-by "," 
--hive-import 
--create-hive-table 
--hive-table sqoop_workspace.helloworld
```